# what is the meaning of FOOBAR=foobar followed by a shell command?

Tags: shell

I see in shell scripts a variable assignment followed (without a semicolon) by a command.  What is the meaning of that?  It does not seem to affect this command, and it does not seem to affect the next command the way normal assignment would:

```
>echo $FOOBAR

>FOOBAR=1 echo $FOOBAR

>echo $FOOBAR

>
```

So, what *does* it do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sets that environment variable to that value only for that process.

Here, **step by step**, is what happens:

- Original command: `FOOBAR=1 echo $FOOBAR`
- Shell performs substitution: command is now `FOOBAR=1 echo`
- Shell `fork(2)`s a new process
- Environment variable is created in the new process: command is now `echo` (with `$FOOBAR` equal to `1`)
- New process is `exec(3)`ed: `\n` is output
- New process exits and is reaped by the shell

At no point does the parent process see the assigned value of `$FOOBAR`.

Comment: What process?  The one on the command line?  No it does not, I showed above.  The parent shell process?  No it does not, I showed above.

Comment: For the process being executed. The variable is replaced before the command is executed.

Comment: I am sorry, I find your answers cryptic.  what is "process being executed".  There is the shell, which could (maybe not for a builtin, but for other commands) spawn a new process.  So there is at least two.  Besides, I showed you above, there is no assignment in force at all.

Comment: The shell has already been executed, therefore it cannot be the process being executed. And as I said, the variable is replaced before the new process is executed. Which means that its value while the process is running is completely irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

On first run of echo $FOOBAR you will get **empty result** on your screen as the FOOBAR variable is **not set** yet.

Then **when you set it to 1**,and run it on the second time it will display **1**.
*Note: This value will be lost when you close your terminal where you wrote these. $ notation in shell and shell scripting in Unix like environments simply denotes a variable.*

**What happens in your case in second command i.e FOOBAR=1 echo $FOOBAR is that the line is not syntactically incorrect but it breaches the contract of equalto(=) which actually does not accept a space thus no error is thrown and FOOBAR=1 is just treated as a parameter and it fails while the command for echo executes successfully**.

I would suggest try this :

```
FOOBAR=1
```

`echo $FOOBAR`

in different lines or

`FOOBAR=1 ; echo $FOOBAR` in one line.